# Why does MongoDB return empty arrays;

Tags: mongodb

First of all my code is obviously simplified. I create a new field named "followers", in order to store followers names, as array type.

**USER SCHEMA**

```
 var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    local:{
        localId:{type:Number},
        username:{type:String},
        email:{type:String},          
        followers:{type:Array}       
    },
    facebook:{
        facebookId: {type:Number},     
        username:{type:String},
        email:{type:String},       
        followers:{type:Array}       
    },
    twitter:{
        twitterId: {type:Number},
        username:{type:String},
        email:{type:String},      
        followers:{type:Array} 
    }
});
```

#### DB record

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("...."), "facebook" : { "facebookId" : 10215321125408144, "username" : "johnny", "email" : "johnny@hotmail.com}, "__v" : 0 }
```

But something weird comes up. When i make a query:

```
User.findOne({$or: [
              {'local.username': 'johnny' },
           { 'facebook.username': 'johnny'  },
            { 'twitter.username': 'johnny'  },
  ]}, function(err, user) {
            if(err){console.log(err);} 
              if(!user){
                console.log('cannot find user');
              }
              if(user){
                console.log('usrInfo is : '+user);
              return res.send(JSON.stringify(user));
            }
        });
```

i get as a result:

```
usrInfo is : { _id: 5a60de744b85e14051e03e2e,
  __v: 0,
  twitter: { followers: [] },
  facebook: 
   { facebookId: .....,
     username: 'johnny',
     email: 'johnny@hotmail.com',
    .............,
     followers: [] },
  local: { followers: [] } }
```

I cannot understand why

```
 twitter: { followers: [] } and   local: { followers: [] }
```

are showing up. Is there any way to avoid this; Because i'm new in MongoDB i would appreciate any explanation why MongoDB does that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue occurs because, according to the [Mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays), fields in your schema with type `Array` *implicitly* have a default value of `[]`. Try setting the default value to `undefined` and see if that resolves your problem:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    local:{
        localId:{type:Number},
        username:{type:String},
        email:{type:String},
        followers:{type:Array, default: undefined}
    },
    facebook:{
        facebookId: {type:Number},
        username:{type:String},
        email:{type:String},
        followers:{type:Array, default: undefined}
    },
    twitter:{
        twitterId: {type:Number},
        username:{type:String},
        email:{type:String},
        followers:{type:Array, default: undefined}
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But if you want to explain this a little bit more.. [ ] means empty. Why MongoDB returns an empty array on non empty query?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "non-empty" in this context. In your specific example, do you mean "non-existent"? If so, it's because of the way your schema is defined. The default value for arrays is an empty array, so when you perform a query and receive the document, any arrays with that default value will be automatically included in your results as an empty array despite not existing in your document. This is likely Mongoose-specific functionality, provided so that you don't have to worry about whether or not an array exists to perform basic array ops like `$push` and `$pull`.